# Python class inheritance. How to get the string from the functions inside the other class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example

```
class Signup:
      def __init__(self):              # i want to call the functions in this class
      self.user_input()
      self.get_password()

      def user_input(self):
          username = input("Enter your username: ")
          return username

      def get_password(self):
          password = input("Enter a password: ")
          return password

class Data(Signup):
      def __init__(self):
      super().__init__()

      self.username = self.user_input()   # When I call these two functions they execute it again
      self.password = self.get_password()
```

So I want the string to be returned when I call those functions in the Data class. The problem is that the function calls itself here again too.

And I know I can just call the functions inside the Data class, but I want to call it in the Signup class and get the string back inside the Data class.

Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Why are these classes two separate classes instead of one? Why does `Signup` ask for a username and password and then throw that information in the trash?

Comment: Limit what side effects you cause in constructors. Calling `input` (indirectly) in a constructor is poor-practice. Pass that data in an let the caller decide where the data comes from. Also, ya, this doesn't seem to make much sense as a class. `Signup` isn't doing anything meaningful, and inheriting from it won't doing anything very useful either.

Comment: @monica So the Signup class calls those functions, and then in the Data class I want to be able to get what those functions return into a string, but instead they call the function again, prompting for more user input

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your issue. What do you mean "When I call these two functions they execute it again"? Your functions will execute twice each ebcause you are calling them twice each, once in the `Signup.__init__` and another, again, in `Data.__init__`.  Of course, as pointed out what you are doing in `Signup` doesn't make sense, you simply discard the input

Comment: I suspect you're under the impression that functions automatically save their return value somewhere. They don't. You can't retrieve an old return value by calling the function again later; that'll just execute the function body again. If you want to save the return value, you have to do that yourself, when you call the function.